# Change background color when using Spinner

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to change the background color of my app when I select a color from my spinner list. But I cannot find ways to achieved this. Can anyone suggest solution for this? My code is below:

SpinnerActivity

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
            (this,R.array.colors,R.layout.dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                    "The color is" + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#000"
tools:context=".SpinnerActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="Pick a Color.Any Color."
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:background="#fff"
    />
```

string

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">UISpinner</string>

<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

<string-array name="colors">
    <item>red</item>
    <item>yellow</item>
    <item>orange</item>
    <item>blue</item>
    <item>green</item>
    <item>white</item>
    <item>pink</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to intilize your RelativeLayout

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.relative_layout) //note you actuall need to set the id in your xml as well
```

then in your onItemSelect for your spinner

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
```

this is really simplified because it only goes one direction. If you wanted to toggle it look into setting boolean flags.